# App not running in the background on real device but running in the simulator

Tags: ios, swift, background, refresh

I'm trying to make a timer application that gives a beep every 10 minutes until the timer countdown is complete.

The timer is counting down even when the app is minimized in the simulator but for some reason the same is not true with the real device.

Background refresh is enabled in the settings for both.

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  timer
//
//  Created by Bharath Reddy on 6/5/23.
//

import UIKit
import AVFoundation

@available(iOS 16.0, *)
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet var timer: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var start: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var reset: UIButton!
    
    var player: AVAudioPlayer!
    
    var sec = 0
    var min = 0
    
    var time1:Timer = Timer()
    var time2:Timer = Timer()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        timer.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
    
    @IBAction func startTimer() {
        timer.resignFirstResponder()
        start.isEnabled = false
        
        min = Int(timer.text ?? "") ?? 0
        
        sec = min * 60
        
        time1 = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 600, target: self, selector: #selector(timer1Counter), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        
        let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "notification-sound-7062", withExtension: "mp3")
        player = try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url!)
        player.play()
        player.play()
        player.play()
        
    }
    
    @IBAction func stopTimer() {
        time1.invalidate()
        time2.invalidate()
        start.isEnabled = true
    }
    
    @objc func timer2Counter() -> Void {
        let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "notification-sound-7062", withExtension: "mp3")
        player = try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url!)
        player.play()
        sec = sec-60
    }
    
    @objc func timer1Counter() -> Void {
        let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "notification-sound-7062", withExtension: "mp3")
        player = try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url!)
        player.play()
        sec = sec-600
        if (sec<=0) {
            time1.invalidate()
        }
        else {
            time2 = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 60, target: self, selector: #selector(timer2Counter), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
        }
    }

}
```

Could someone help me with the same?

I was expecting that the timer would countdown in the background but doesn't seem to be the case. Should I be using the date function?

Comment: You may find the following [search results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bios%5D+timer+background) helpful.